# columns in lightning aura table is not visible to certain profiles

Tags: lightning-aura-components, table, aura-attribute

The Columns Access Revoked and Tax Status are not visible in lightning aura table of a page because there are two issues in the code below:

1. currentUserProfile (String) was compared in permissionMap which is Boolean
2. permissionMap content was never initialized

What changes should be made in the code below to make this available and visible to the following profiles:

1. System_Admin
2. Service
3. Service_Read_Only
4. Operations

How to initialized the content in permissionMap?

When I removed the if condition the columns are showing but I need to add the if condition to make it only visible to a certain profiles.

Here is the code

Component.cmp

```
<!-- <aura:attribute name="permissionMap" type="Map" default="{System_Admin: false, Service: false,                                                            Service_Read_Only: false, Operations: false }" />   --> 

<aura:attribute name="permissionMap" type="Map" default="{ a: 'System_Admin', b: 'Service', c: 'Service_Read_Only', d: 'Operations' }" />                                   

<aura:attribute name="currentUserProfile" type="String" />
```

ComponentHelper.js

```
initUI : function(component, event, helper){
    //get and set the permissionMap if the user has the custom permission

    let getPermissions = component.get("c.getPermissionMap");
    getPermissions.setParams({
        "permissionMap": component.get("v.permissionMap")
    });
    getPermissions.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        let state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.permissionMap", response.getReturnValue());
            var currentUserProfile = component.get("v.currentUserProfile");
            var financialAccountRecordType = component.get("v.financialAccountRecordType");
           // var permissionMap = component.get("v.permissionMap");
            var columns = [];
            columns.push({label: 'Contact', type: 'button', initialWidth: 300, typeAttributes: { label: { fieldName: 'ContactName'}, name: 'nav_contact', disabled: {fieldName: 'disableContact'}, variant: "base"}});
            columns.push({label: 'Entity', type: 'button', initialWidth: 300, typeAttributes: { label: { fieldName: 'EntityName'}, name: 'nav_entity', disabled: {fieldName: 'disableEntity'}, variant: "base"}});
            if(currentUserProfile === component.get("v.permissionMap")['System_Admin']){    
                columns.push({label: 'Access Revoked', fieldName: 'ConsentWithdrawn', type: 'boolean'});
               }
            columns.push({label: 'Relationship', fieldName: 'Relationship__c', type: 'text'});

            columns.push({label: 'Date of Birth', fieldName: 'DateOfBirth', type: 'date'});
             if((currentUserProfile === permissionMap.Service || currentUserProfile === permissionMap.Service_Read_Only || currentUserProfile === permissionMap.Operations || currentUserProfile === permissionMap.System_Admin) && financialAccountRecordType == "Bank Account"){
                columns.push({label: "Tax Status", fieldName: "TaxStatus", type: "text"});
               }
            columns.push({label: 'Preference', type: 'button', initialWidth: 90, typeAttributes: { label: 'Edit', name: 'edit_pref', title: 'Edit', disabled: {fieldName: 'disableEdit'}}});
            component.set("v.columns", columns);

        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(getPermissions);

 },
```

FAccountController

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static Map<String, Boolean> getPermissionMap(Map<String, Boolean> permissionMap) {
        for (String p : permissionMap.keySet()) {
            permissionMap.put(p, FeatureManagement.checkPermission(p));
        }
        return permissionMap;
    }
```

Comment: adding this again since it is not showing:                                                             Component.cmp

<aura: attribute name = "permissionMap" type="Map"  default="{ System_Admin:'false',  Service:'false',  Service_Read_Only:'false', Operations:'false'}" />                                     

<aura:attribute name="currentUserProfile" type="String" />

Comment: Updated with latest code, I cannot comment on the thread on the answer so I am commenting here.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for retrieving the value of the map is documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_collection.htm)

If you have a map attribute like below

```
<aura:attribute name="sectionLabels" type="Map" default="{ a: 'label1', b: 'label2' }" />
```

Then you can retrieve its value by key using below

```
cmp.get("v.sectionLabels")['a']
```

So in your example change your code as shown below

```
if(currentUserProfile === component.get('v.permissionMap')['System_Admin']){    
        columns.push({label: 'Access Revoked', fieldName: 'ConsentWithdrawn', type: 'boolean'});

 if((currentUserProfile === component.get('v.permissionMap')['Service'] || currentUserProfile === component.get('v.permissionMap')['Service_Read_Only'] || currentUserProfile === component.get('v permissionMap')['Operations'] || currentUserProfile === component.get('v.permissionMap')['System_Admin']) && financialAccountRecordType === "Bank Account"){
        columns.push({label: "Tax Status", fieldName: "TaxStatus", type: "text"});
```

**Minor Improvement**

Note in Javascript == is different than === and i suggest you to use === for strict equality comparison.

Comment: You mean like this ........ <aura:attribute name="permissionMap" type="Map" default="{ a: 'System_Admin', b: 'Service', c: Service_Read_Only, d: Operations }" />                                                    I am getting error on  ...  if(currentUserProfile === permissionMap.['System_Admin']){    
        columns.push({label: 'Access Revoked', fieldName: 'ConsentWithdrawn', type: 'boolean'});     the error is ... Parsing error: Unexpected token [ : Source

Comment: Just fixed the code.Try the one I have now

Comment: Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Invalid key permissionMap]
Callback failed: apex://FinancialAccountController/ACTION$getPermissionMap

Comment: That seems something to do with your controller function. Sounds like another question where you want to add more details with lot more code

Comment: trying to add the code but it is not allowing how can I add more code

Comment: edit your question, and add it there

Comment: updated - the error is in the if condition.....  if(currentUserProfile === component.get('permissionMap')['System_Admin']

Comment: Sorry it was typo from me, use if(currentUserProfile === component.get('v.permissionMap')['System_Admin']

Comment: same error .   can you look at this in the code..   var permissionMap = component.get("v.permissionMap");

Comment: I dont think you are following what i have there. The syntax for reading from map is componet.get("v. permissionMap")

Comment: sorry. I have updated the code but now updated same code here... same error still.

Comment: added code for FAController apex

Comment: Note that you dont need this line anymore             var permissionMap = component.get("v.permissionMap");

Comment: Also please use the code i have in my answer for those conditions.

Comment: OK, I have commented that line....                                                                        same issue... the problem with if condition Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Invalid key permissionMap] Callback failed: apex://FinancialAccountController/ACTION$getPermissionMap

Comment: Please update your latest code in the question.